# Is it important to play Captain Spirit before Life is Strange 2?

Tags: life-is-strange-2, captain-spirit

Context - I actually 100%'d Captain Spirit on the PS4 a couple months back, but I recently bought Life is Strange 2 on PC so the save data won't transfer. I know that decisions you made in Captain Spirit have some impacts on LiS2 episode 2, but I'm really excited to just power through LiS2 so I don't really want to replay CS on PC since I already played it so recently. Does it have a big enough impact that I should power through it again, or will I not miss anything if I just skip it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2018-06-10-25-minutes-with-life-is-strange-2s-brilliantly-unexpected-free-prequel), you can play Life is Strange 2 without having to play Captain Spirit.

The article did go on to quote a statement from the co-director stating that importing your save data from Captain Spirit would provide a better experience for Life is Strange 2.

> "You can play Captain Spirit on its own, and also you can play Life is Strange 2 without playing Captain Spirit, but for us the best way will be to play this before LiS2 because, as we said, there are some consequences, but the player will also have some interesting information to go into Life is Strange 2 with,"  Koch continued.

Answer (score 0):

You should first play Life is Strange 2 Episode 1 its now free on steam, and then play Captain Spirit. Then If you bought episode 2 of Life is Strange 2 then play that.

Comment: Why is that the case?